# format Excel data by removing null values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datatable, excel-2010, formattable

I have data like below.

Columns on which we should group are : coulmn1,coulmn2,coulmn3,coulmn4,coulmn5,coulmn9

what can be the best possible way to do it. I tried to use **vlookup, merge, concat** to make a primary key and merge but somehow all my rows were not found.

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 | column7 | column8 | column9 | column10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Greater Country1 | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz1 |  |  | state | 1 |
| See Data | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz2 |  |  | state | 2 |
| Greater Country1 | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz3 |  |  | state | 3 |
| See Data | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz4 |  |  | state | 4 |
| Greater Country1 | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn |  | Type AB |  |  |  |
| See Data | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn |  | Type AB |  |  |  |
| Greater Country1 | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn |  | Type AB |  |  |  |
| See Data | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn |  | Type AB |  |  |  |
| Alpha | DataColumn | massWeight | DIFFERENT COLUMN ITEM | ItemColumn | xyz |  |  | state | 11 |
| AlphBetaa | DataColumn | massWeight | VERY DIFFERENT COLUMN ITEM | ItemColumn |  | Type AB | A | state | 12 |

Expected outcome:

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 | column7 | column8 | column9 | column10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Greater Country1 | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz1 | Type AB |  | state | 1 |
| See Data | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz2 | Type AB |  | state | 2 |
| Greater Country1 | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz3 | Type AB |  | state | 3 |
| See Data | DataColumn | massWeight | ColumnNameSame | ItemColumn | xyz4 | Type AB |  | state | 4 |
| Alpha | DataColumn | massWeight | DIFFERENT COLUMN ITEM | ItemColumn | xyz |  |  | state | 11 |
| AlphBetaa | DataColumn | massWeight | VERY DIFFERENT COLUMN ITEM | ItemColumn |  | Type AB | A | state | 12 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the logic to keep the rows in the output? It seems that you need to filter by column 10 non empty values, but I don't know if that is the logic.